# Self bot unable to run function with cogs?

Tags: python, discord.py

I am running this script that I found from a YouTube tutorial, and it was working earlier. Now it seems to not be working anymore.

> Script that isn't working

```
import asyncio
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='', help_command=None, self_bot=False)

class SelfBot(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.command()
    async def sendMessage(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send("Send Message")

client.add_cog(SelfBot(client))
client.run(token, bot=False)
```

it seems to be as if it is getting "stuck" at `@commands.command()` and won't run the sendMessage function. My bot also appears to be online once the script is running. Any ideas on how to fix it?

Another thing that i found interesting is that one of my scripts that i created does work how it was intended.

> Script that is working

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    await asyncio.sleep(1)

    with message.channel.typing():
        await asyncio.sleep(2)

    await message.channel.send("test")
    return


bot.run(token, bot=False)
```

This will message me test once I send a message to the server.

Comment: Cogs in general are in a separate file, refer [this](https://gist.github.com/EvieePy/d78c061a4798ae81be9825468fe146be) . I would suggest against using a self-bot as your account is liable to be disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command might not be working because you have a `on_message` event. [`on_message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_message#discord.on_message) events have the priority on commands and if you don't [process them](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=process#discord.ext.commands.Bot.process_commands), none of them will be able to be executed.

What you have to add is in your `on_message` event:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    await asyncio.sleep(1)

    with message.channel.typing():
        await asyncio.sleep(2)

    await message.channel.send("test")
    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

If it doesn't solve the problem, it might also come from your `commands.Bot` variable. For an unkown reason, you seem to have two `commands.Bot` variables: `client` and `bot`. You should only have one.

Also, I saw you set your prefix as `''`, if you don't want any error like `Command not found`, you should set a prefix (eg. `!`, `$`, `;`, ...).

Also, as @InsertCheesyLine recommended it, you should separate your cogs in different files and put them in a folder nammed `cogs`, like so:

Main file (eg. `bot.py`)

```py
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

extensions = ['cogs.test'] #cogs.(filename)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for extension in extensions:
        bot.load_extension(extension)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Bot is ready to go!')

bot.run('TOKEN')
```

One of your cogs (eg. `cogs/test.py`)

```py
from discord.ext import commands

#This is a cog example, you'll have to adapt it with your code
class Test(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.Cog.listener() #equivalent to @bot.event
    async def on_message(self, message):
        if 'test' in message.content:
            await message.channel.send('Test Message')
        
        await self.bot.process_commands(message)

    @commands.command()
    async def ping(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send('Pong!')

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Test(bot))
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! I have a couple of questions, however. Firstly, in the bot.py, I should have ```bot.run('TOKEN', bot=False)``` right? Second, in test.py one of the lines says ```await bot.process_commands(message)``` and seems to be giving me an error ```NameError: name 'bot' is not defined```. I removed that line and everything seems to work fine. Last thing, how would i make the bot, as soon as it starts, or once it is ready, send a message to a text channel of a guild that it is already in instead of triggering the function with !ping?

Comment: Can you go a little bit more in depth on how to add an ```on_ready``` event in the test.py file?  I attempted to add a ```on_ready``` function to the test.py file, but was unsure what to set the decorator to. I tried to set it to ```@bot.event``` but obviously, ```bot``` isn't defined. I don't want to set it to ```@commands.command()```, because that would require you to type in ```!function``` to one of the servers channels. Any ideas?

Comment: Inside cogs, you have to replace `bot` by `self.bot`. If you have any further questions, please make some researchs before asking here, you can also post other questions if you have errors that you can't solve by yourself. Now, to avoid wasting other's time and for clarity, could you delete your comments?